# How does one query a postgres array using the gin index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres array column with a gin index:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    tags character varying(255)[]
);

CREATE INDEX index_things_on_tags ON things USING gin (tags);
```

There are a few ways to check for the presence of an element in the column, using various array operators. Here are the ones I've seen:

1. `select * from things where 'blue' = ANY (tags)`
2. `select * from things where tags <@ '{"blue"}'`
3. `select * from things where '{"blue","yellow"}' && tags;`

In postgres 9.3:

- Will the first one use the gin index?
- I'm pretty sure the second one will use the index. However, it is different from the first. it doesn't allow me to check if blue is one of the tags, it requires me to specify the exact array. Is there a way to make the style of syntax in 2 achieve what 1 is achieving?
- In the third, I want any row that has any one of blue or yellow. Will this query use the gin index? If not, how can I do this query with an index?

Comment: Just run `explain analyze` and all your questions will be answered

Comment: #2 should be `select * from things where tags @> '{"blue"}`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not test and see?

```
regress=> SET enable_seqscan  = off;
SET

regress=> explain select * from things where 'blue' = ANY (tags);
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on things  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000037.67 rows=6 width=36)
   Filter: ('blue'::text = ANY ((tags)::text[]))
(2 rows)

regress=> explain select * from things where tags <@ '{"blue"}';
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on things  (cost=12.05..21.52 rows=6 width=36)
   Recheck Cond: (tags <@ '{blue}'::character varying[])
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_things_on_tags  (cost=0.00..12.05 rows=6 width=0)
         Index Cond: (tags <@ '{blue}'::character varying[])
(4 rows)

regress=> explain select * from things where '{"blue","yellow"}' && tags;
                                     QUERY PLAN                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on things  (cost=12.10..22.78 rows=12 width=36)
   Recheck Cond: ('{blue,yellow}'::character varying[] && tags)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_things_on_tags  (cost=0.00..12.09 rows=12 width=0)
         Index Cond: ('{blue,yellow}'::character varying[] && tags)
(4 rows)
```

So Pg is using the index for the `&&` and `<@` queries, but not for `= ANY (...)`.

I'm sure it'd be possible to teach Pg to transform `x = ANY (y)` into `ARRAY[x] @> y`, but it doesn't at the moment.

What 2 does is exactly what you say you want. Test if "blue" is one of the tags. It's not an equality test, it's a membership test.

---

However, if instead of checking a literal value like `'blue'` you use a value from another table, I noticed that:

- `somethings.tag = ANY (otherthings.tags)` was faster if the number of `otherthings` rows was small (it does a sequantial scan on `otherthings` and uses the index for `somethings`)
- `ARRAY[somethings.tag] <@ otherthings.tags` was faster if the number of `otherthings` is larger because it uses the gin index on `otherthings` but it seems the `ARRAY[]` construct forces a sequantial scan on `somethings`. If however you don't need to construct the array, it should use the gin index on both sides.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with `SET enable_seqscan  = off;` in order to test index usage on small data.

Comment: here's what i'm observing about the behavior of 2: https://gist.github.com/jjb/9281339

Comment: @JohnBachir Reverse it; `@>`. BTW, http://sqlfiddle.com/ is much more useful for that kind of thing.

Comment: oh right. hah! thanks. also didn't know about sqlfiddle.com, very nice!